# Is there any way to pass NDB kind as string?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Currently I use the code like below -

```
Price.query().fetch(keys_only=True))
```

The `Price` here is hardcoded kind name. Is there any way to have something like:

```
def get_kind_keys(kindname):
    return Kind(kindname).query().fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ndb` keeps a `dict` with all models, you can try it for yourself:

```py
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

print ndb.Model._kind_map
```

Your code snippet will end up something like this:

```py
def get_kind_keys(kindname):
    return ndb.Model._kind_map[kindname].query().fetch(keys_only=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`ndb.Query` accepts a kind in its constructor. You could implement `get_kind_keys` as:

```
def get_kind_keys(kindname):
    return ndb.Query(kind=kindname).fetch(keys_only=True)
```

What may make using `_kind_map` more appealing is that if you use `PolyModel`, calling `query()` on the model will properly filter for the desired class. Otherwise, these two solutions are equivalent. You can look at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/source/browse/ndb/model.py#3331) for `Model._query` to see exactly what the difference is.